# Command dialect is not supported by SQLNCLI11 provider SQL Server 2012

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, sql-server-2012, sqlncli, sqloledb

We are using classic ASP and SQL Server 2012 standard edition.

Our connection string is as below

```
provider=SQLNCLI11;Data Source=xxx; MultiSubnetFailover=True; Initial Catalog=xxx; User ID = xxx; Password =xxxxxx; DataTypeCompatibility=80; Integrated Security=SSPI; MARS Connection=true;
```

We were using SQLOLEDB provider and it was working fine in our application. When we tried to change provider to SQL Native client (SQLNCLI 11) it was throwing error

> Command dialect is not supported by SQLNCLI11 provider SQL Server 2012

on below line

```vb
set ocmd = server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")  'created command object
oCmd.Dialect = "{5D531CB2-E6Ed-11D2-B252-00C04F681B71}"  ' assigned dialect
oCmd.Execute , , 1024     'Error line
```

Comment: Surprised how little there is on the web about this issue.

Comment: Remove setting the `oCmd.Dialect`.

Answer (score 1):

Had to look this one up not seen it for a while.

The `Dialect` property of the `ADODB.Command` object has this description

> <sup>From [ADO API Reference - Dialect Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675547(v=vs.85).aspx)</sup>
>   *Indicates the dialect of the `CommandText` or `CommandStream` properties. The dialect defines the syntax and general rules that **the provider** uses to parse the string or stream.*

So the `Dialect` is specific to a provider, now that you have changed the provider the Command Dialect is not longer supported for that specific GUID reference, that isn't to say that SQLNCLI11 won't support others.

The specific `Dialect`

```
{5D531CB2-E6Ed-11D2-B252-00C04F681B71}
```

Provides support for [Applying an XSL Transformation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258688(v=sql.80).aspx) with the SQLXMLOLEDB provider.

I doubt there is an equivalent setting in the SQL Server Native Client because SQL Server 2012 supports the `FOR XML` clause for returning XML data.